# While loop trouble

Tags: c

```
/*Taking input from user to calculate the cost of a travel plan                                                                                                                                                                            
using the number of travelers/ number of stops/ cost of each stop                                                                                                                                                                          
giving both the half cost of a trip and its full price*/

int calculate( int total);

#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    float  customer, stops, response,  cost, i, stop, total, halfcost, totaltrip;
    i=0;
    printf("Welcome to Airline express.\n");

    printf("Would you like to calculate the cost of a trip?");

    scanf("%f", &response);
    while ( response != 0 )
    {
        printf("Please enter how many customer will be traveling. Children under 12 are counted as .5:");
        scanf("%f", &customer);
        if (customer < 0)
            customer = 3;

        printf("Please enter how many stops there are:");
        scanf("%f", &stop);

        while (i<stop)
        {
            printf("Please enter cost of the next stop:");
            scanf("%f", &cost);
            if (cost < 0)
                cost = 100;
            total +=cost;
            i++;
        }

        halfcost = calculate(total);
        printf("Half cost is: %f", halfcost);


        totaltrip = total * customer;
        printf("Total cost for trip is: %f\n", totaltrip);

        printf("Would you like to calculate another trip?");
        scanf("%f", &response);
    }
    return 0;
}

int calculate( int total)
{
    return total/2;
}
```

I'm having issues with the inputs, I'm trying to make the loop run as the user request another calculations. But when ever it re runs another test it keeps the input of the previous test is there a way to reset the variables to 0? 
Ive tried assign all of the variable inside and outside of the loop but I'm kinda lost on what to go from here.

Comment: You really should learn about integers.  `float` isn't an appropriate data type for things that are countable (like the number of stops).  `total` is one of the few variables that probably should accept fractional values, and you pass it in an `int` parameter.

Comment: You never initialize `total` (even the first time around); it is not guaranteed to be 0 before you start adding `cost` s to it.

Comment: `response` should also be a char... just a Y/y or N/n is an intuitive input.

Answer (score 2):

Move the declaration of the variables to sit inside the loop.

```
while ( response != 0 )
{
    float  customer = 0, stops = 0, response = 0,  cost = 0, i = 0, stop = 0, total = 0, halfcost = 0, totaltrip = 0;
    ...
}
```

Comment: It work :D but there is one slight problem Could I declare them at the top of the function instead of inside the loop or must it be inside the loop for it to work properly

Comment: Noting that the requirement for variable declaration in C is that it be at the start of a block; very often this (mis)interpreted as requiring it to be the start of the function. Put your variable declarations as close as you can to where you need them is a useful pattern.

Comment: Thanks I was thinking the same guess I'll have to argue with my professor on her preference.

Comment: This is confusing issues.  More localised scope is great in and of itself (except response), but the real issue is that `total` wasn't initialised to 0 inside the loop.

Comment: @Tony Nor was i. The issues being confused are declaration/definition and initialization, and I'm not sure the OP  grasps this. Regardless of where the professor prefers the declarations (and if she doesn't prefer them as close to use as possible then she's incompetent to teach), *logic* dictates where the variables should be set.

Comment: @Keith "Noting that the requirement for variable declaration in C" While there was such a requirement 20 years ago, there isn't one today.